# View & Edit Cloud SQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, xampp, google-cloud-sql

I'm fairly new to working with live MySQL database and so I just wanted to ask if it possible to edit and view a google cloud SQL mirror using xampp phpmyadmin? if so may I request a bit of guideline to achieve this task or reference to documentation containing relevant guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with a SQL GUI like [MySQL WorkBench](https://www.mysql.com/fr/products/workbench/) which is free.

You need to provide :

- **host** (this correspond to cloud database public IP address)
- **database** name (you need to create a database inside Google Cloud SQL)
- **user name** (you need to create a user inside Google Cloud SQL, or use `root` user)
- **user password**

Moreover, you have to authorized your personal public IP address. (Connections tab on Google Cloud SQL)

There is a lot of GUI for SQL database, one of my favorites is [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/)